# Pingfederate: data.app.contextMap.trackingid (tid)

Tags: single-sign-on, ping, pingfederate

Does anybody know how and when **Pingfederate** generates the **data.app.contextMap.trackingid** (tid) and how long this is valid or used? The tracking ID is given out on screen when error occur.

Comment: I answered the question, but I'm curious as to why you ask. I may be able to better answer your question if I understand what you're actually trying to do, instead of just telling what the TID is and does.

Answer (score 0):

The tracking ID is generated on the client's first interaction with PingFederate, and is valid (and carried forward) for the user's entire session life. It is effectively the user's session identifier.

Comment: Hi Andrew,
thanks a lot for your answer. I was asking out of curiosity because I was tracking an error in Kibana and only had the tid which I found in many logentries throughout the day.